# Getting param from friendly url like http://localhost:3000/user/adem-balka with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

So I want to display posts for an user in his/her profile page as at top user details, below all the posts.

I know I can get param from a url like **http://localhost:3000/posts?category=article**

with

```
if params[:category]
  @category_id = Category.find_by(title: params[:category]).id
  @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id)
end
```

---

but param doesn't work when I have an url like **http://localhost:3000/user/adem-balka**

**So, how can I get user name to find its id and pull posts with that user id?**

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you accept one of these answers? I only ask because I notice [you just asked another question where you accepted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180987/rails-5-query-to-pull-posts-from-same-category-other-than-the-post-im-currently) yet neglected to accept an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the answers. I learned from them

and this solved my problem

```
  @user_id = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @posts = Post.where(user_id: @user_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of a parameter in a url is set in your routes file.

If you look at your routes in `config/routes.rb`, you should  be able to find the line(s) that corresponds to the user model. It should look something like this:

`get '/users/:name', to: 'users#show'`

This means that if you go to /users/adem-balka, params[:name] will be set to 'adem-balka'. You can then access the parameter in the corresponding controller function.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a path parameter, where `adem-balka` is say `params[:username]`.

Assuming you have no forward slashes or dots in your parameter, this is as simple as adding `/:username` as part of your route, e.g.

```
get '/users/:username', to: 'users#show'


# in the controller
@user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
```

This is all covered in the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide.

Note that the routes generated `resources` already contain the `:id` path parameter for you (for `show`, `edit`, etc.). But even if you change the controller, the generated helpers (e.g. `users_path(@user)`) will use the id.

To make it work with `resources` using say `username` instead of `id` however (e.g. `users_path(@user)` giving `/users/ben` instead of `/users/5`), you need to also override the `to_param` method, e.g.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def to_param
    username #rather than id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# routes.rb
get '/users/:username' => 'users#posts'


# users_controller.rb
def posts
  username = params[:username]
  # etc..
end
```

This is described in the [Rails Docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters) as Routing Parameters.