# Rails 5 Query to pull posts from same category other than the post I'm currently viewing

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to display 3 other posts from same category at post details page. So I have this query:

```
  def show
    @posts_from_same_category = Post.where(category_id: @post.category_id).limit(3).order("RANDOM()")
  end
```

So the page structure is like:

- Post title
- Posts text
- (title) More posts from same category
- Other post title 1
- Other post title 2
- Other post title 3

It returns all posts including the posts I'm viewing. **How can I write the query to pull posts other than the one I'm currently viewing?**

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another condition to exclude current post:

```
@other_posts = @post.category.posts.where.not(id: @post.id).limit(3).order('RANDOM()')
```

Comment: rails 4 has [where.not](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot) which reads a little nicer: `.where.not(id: @post:id)`

Comment: Nice! I didn't know we could write **where** multiple times. Thank you